# SPRING DATA JPA - I need to fetch data based on timestamp column where month (int) as a parameter in native query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

UI sends month parameter as int

```java
@GetMapping("/{Monthnumber}")
Public List<FunctionList> getByMonth(@pathvariable("MonthNumber") int month)
```

Using the above API

For example, if my month is Feb the parameter value would be 2 but in my oracle db the column contains timestamp data `22-FEB-22 11.00.00.00000000 AM`

Tried below IN REPO

```java
@QUERY("SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE month(timestamp_date) = ?1)
List<Functionlist> getByMonth(int month number)
```

How to correctly query this

Comment: You have the extract function from oracle that can get your month number like that : `@Query("SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM timestamp_date) = ?1")
List getByMonth(int monthNumber);`

Comment: I think this works, i have written the query in repo class should I mention the db table name instead of entity class name which mapped to the table ?

Comment: The entity class is used to represent the data in your application, while the database table stores the actual data. So yes, you should ;)